# C++ access member-function from friend class

Tags: c++, friend, friend-class

Is there a way to access member-function from the friend class?

```
// foo.h

template<typename T>
class A
{
    bool operator()(Item* item)
    {
        ObjectClass c = get_class_from_item(item); // compiler error
        ...
    }
};

class B
{
    ...
    template<typename T> friend class A;
    ...
    ObjectClass get_class_from_item(Item* item);
};
```

If it matters I use gcc 4.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `get_class_from_item` is supposed to be some kind of Factory function, which it seems to be, you need to make it static. You get the error because your compiler is looking for a function named `get_class_from_item` in class `A`. It will never see the function in `B` because it is not in the scope and you don't have an instance of class `B`. Here is some more explanation on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_function.

This should do it:

```
class A
{
    bool operator()(Item * item)
    {
        ObjectClass c = B::get_class_from_item(item);
        ...
    }
};

class B
{
    static ObjectClass get_class_from_item(Item* item);
};
```

Also, is there a reason that `A` needs to be a friend class of `B`? Or did you just do that trying to get `get_class_from_item`to work? Does `A` need to be able to access some private elements of `B`? Think carefully about this, most of the time there are better ways of obtaining what you want instead of throwing away all encapsulation by using `friend`.

**[Edit]** Removed lines from code example to strip it to the bare minimum.

Comment: It's not a factory function. It just gets an `item` and returns `ObjectClass` that item holds like: `return classes[item->data(...)]`. OTOH I can't make `get_class_from_item` static, because it uses some members that cannot be static (they are changed in run-time).

Comment: The deal is that `A` doesn't have enough information to do its task. So I probably should fix the design. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

No, since `get_class_from_item` is a member function you need an instance of class `B` to call it.